# Pyinstaller and import issue with wx.lib.pubsub

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, pyinstaller, pypubsub

My Python GUI app, works perfectly but when I try to create an executable I tried with pyinstaller (3.3.dev0+483c819) command:

```
pyinstaller gui_app.py
```

I get the follow issue:

```
7699 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-wx.lib.pubsub.py"...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 41, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 36, in walk_packages
  File "<string>", line 20, in walk_packages
  File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\pubsub\core\arg1\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise RuntimeError(msg)
RuntimeError: Should not import this directly, used by pubsub.core if applicable
8006 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.publisher" not found!
8008 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.listenerimpl" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.publishermixin" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.datamsg" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.topicargspecimpl" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.topicmgrimpl" not found!
```

The executable is "successfully" created but when I launch it i get the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "upload_test_run_dynamic_clean.py", line 21, in <module>
    from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\pubsub\pub.py", line 35, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 389, in load_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\pubsub\core\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
ImportError: No module named publisher
```

I tried to add hookspath is the spec file (it exists a hook for wx.lib.pubsub already in pyinstaller hooks folder) but it did not work, or I did something wrong.

Is there an order to import wx and other submodules. 
I have this in my code

```
import wx
import wx.lib.pubsub.setuparg1
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
import wx.lib.agw.pybusyinfo as PBI
from wx.lib.scrolledpanel import ScrolledPanel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
8006 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.publisher" not found!
8008 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.listenerimpl" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.publishermixin" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.datamsg" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.topicargspecimpl" not found!
8009 WARNING: Hidden import "wx.lib.pubsub.core.topicmgrimpl" not found!
```

These modules are missing in core, move them back there in case you have misplaced the modules.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the import of those modules is done in the subfolder kwargs, but those files actually need to be placed in the root folder.

So I just copied those files from

```
Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\pubsub\core\kwargs
```

to

```
Lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx\lib\pubsub\core
```

and now IT WORKS!

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, which is still present after the release of pyinstaller 3.4. This is a known issue when using any of wx.lib.pubsub, PyPubSub, or pypubsub with pyinstaller. See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1530 ; apparently imports are handled in a way that is tricky to work around. PyPubSub and pypubsub are forks of the same code base, and will have the same problem. If do not want to hack the libs of the wx distribution with every release, your options include:

- Switch to PyDispatcher, blinker, or another simpler pubsub library
- Modify PyPubSub so that it loads modules in a way that is compatible with pyinstaller, and submit the PR back to the project

The path of least resistance seems to be to find a different pubsub library. I switched to blinker, which is minimal and good for smaller projects.

Another tip: be aware that with pyinstaller there is usually one version combination that is stable, and this varies per-platform.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently and I found another solution that worked for me. I replaced `from wx.lib.pubsub import pub` with `from pubsub import pub`. You may have do a `pip install pypubsub` to get the needed package. You can find more information here:
https://github.com/schollii/pypubsub/issues/7

Comment: Did this work with PyPubSub 4.0.3, pyinstaller 3.4 and python 3? I have been unable to get PyPubSub or pypubsub to load after compiling.